# /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 777, should be 0

Tags: sudo

When I use the command like:

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

I get an error like `/etc/sudoers is owned by uid 777, should be 0`.  What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Have you run anything like `sudo chown 777` on any files/directories by any chance? If not, someone has broken into your system. If you did, then **don't ever** do that again. It's apparent that whoever did it meant to use `chmod` instead of `chown`, but even with `chmod` it is **very** wrong.

You have to boot into recovery mode, or live session, and change its ownership and permission back to normal

```
chown root: /etc/sudoers
chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
```

Make sure you understand what `chown` does before using it. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: I used the command,sudo chown 777 myfolder it seems to be error .what i install also the same error. chown: changing ownership of `/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted.

Comment: @padma, Well firstly, `sudo chown 777 myfolder` will set the ownership of myfolder to 777, which is likely a non-existant user, and secondly, you must've added some other stuff on that command, because somehow you managed to run it on `/etc/sudoers` too. Let's hope you didn't change any other system files. Anyway, since you can't use sudo anymore, you have to boot into recovery mode to get a root shell, or boot the Ubuntu CD and fix it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I got also some success with:

`pkexec chown root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and because it was so difficult I made a video to explain the solution. Even though this isn't for Ubuntu the fix should work just as well.

http://youtu.be/gh5CDtRX7Ho

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks - your video totally helped me get out of this pickle on AWS.